# Apache2 Headers not working correctly

Tags: php, apache, iframe, http-headers, clickjacking

Having issues with iframes (have no control as these come with the system I have) and the cross-site stuff.

Have added the usual `X-Frame-Options` to my `.htaccess` file to include the directive to allow it to allow the iframe from this other system that wants to iframe the site. No problem at first.

> <IfModule mod_headers.c>
>   Header always set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://otherhost" 
>   </IfModule>

And I can confirm that the above is taking effect as I have messed with the header content and it is reflected.

For some reason, I keep seeing the header `X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM https://otherhost, SAMEORIGIN` with this additional `SAMEORIGIN`, which of course is not valid and fails within the browsers, ultimately resulting in the browser falling back to `DENY`, which then means the iframe is not shown.

The apache2 specs states for the `set` option, that;

> The response header is set, replacing any previous header with this name. The value may be a format string.

Yet I do not see it replacing the string.  If I `curl` the login page, it presents correctly, if I inspect it in the chrome/safari inspector, it shows the additional `, SAMEORIGIN` and then complains that it's not valid.

I've even tried using the `unset` option for the `Header` directive, but it still keeps producing this header.

**Is the `Header` directive post or pre output?** as this is driving me nuts and wasting so much time for a simple thing.

Comment: Looks like that `SAMEORIGIN` is not coming form apache. Perhaps a proxy/router/something between your browsers and apache is inserting it?

Comment: Sounds possible as I know that all the traffic on this network (including SSL) is proxied.  :(    Thanks for the idea. :)